# command line: how to copy files with the same name into one directory without overwriting

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, command-prompt

I have the next folder structure:

```
C:\My Test\
C:\My Test\Folder_1\activity[1].json
C:\My Test\Folder_N\...\activity[1].json
```

### My goal is to:

copy all `activity*json` files to `D:\Output\` directory to have something like this:

```
D:\Output\activity[%unique_variable%].json
D:\Output\activity[%unique_variable%].json
```

My code:

```
for /R "C:\My Test\" %%f in (activity*.json) do ( copy %%f D:\Output\activity%random%.json )
```

Comment: [SO] isn't a script writing service, you should show your code - even if not working properly. To what do you refer with `%unique_variable%`? An ascending counter, a random number?

Comment: @LotPings my current script is `for /R "C:\My Test\" %%f in (activity*.json) do (
copy %%f D:\Output\activity%random%.json
)` but I always have one file overwrited N times

Comment: PLease edit the question to include your code; don't put code in comments. I did it for you this time. Since you put the copy command in a (code block) you need delayed expansion and as the path contains a space you've to double quote `copy "%%f" ...`

Comment: So increment %random% each time you do a copy in the parentheses.

Comment: @Mark Setchell I'm a beginner in scripting, so, unfortunately, I have no idea how to implement your recommendation :(

Comment: Look for "Arithmetic expressions" `SET /a` here https://ss64.com/nt/set.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something as follows:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "type=.json"
set "source=c:\my test"
set "dest=d:\output"

for /r "%source%" %%e in ("*%type%") do (
  for %%i in ("%dest%\%%~ne*") do (
    set /a count+=1
  )
  set "source=%%e"
  set "dest=%dest%\%%~ne"
  xcopy "!source!" "!dest!!count!%type%*"
  set count=
)
```

If the file to be copied already exists in the destination folder, a numeric value will be added to the file name and incremented for every duplicate found.

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /R "C:\My Test\" %%f in (activity*.json) do (
 call :select
 copy %%f D:\Output\activity!unique!.json
)

...
goto :eof

:select
set /a unique=%random%
if exist "D:\Output\activity!unique!.json" goto Select
goto :eof
```

Your error is the way in which the batch parser works with code blocks (parenthesised lines of code) - by replacing any `%var%` with the value of that variable at the time. Hence `%random%` is replaced by a random value, but it's not re-chosen each iteration, only once at parse-time.

The crude way is to invoke `delayedexpansion` (ther are many articles on SO about this - use `search`) and replace `%random%` with `!random!` - but there is a small possibility that a particular random value may be chosen more than once in any particular run, or that the proposed new filename already exists.

Therefore, use a subroutine to choose the destination filename and check that the proposed name is unique within the subroutine (which allows `goto`s)

The downside is that you should skip over the subroutine when terminating your batch, so the rest of your batch is represented by `...` and the `goto :eof` skips over the remaining code (see `call /?` from the prompt for documentation)

Another approach would be to assign the filename to be moved to a variable and move it within the subroutine. This has the advantage of not requiring `delayedexpansion`

```
for /R "C:\My Test\" %%f in (activity*.json) do (
 set "moveme=%%f"
 call :select
)

...
goto :eof

:select
set /a unique=%random%
if exist "D:\Output\activity%unique%.json" goto Select
copy "%moveme%" D:\Output\activity%unique%.json
goto :eof
```